# Why can't I import my own Qt module?

Tags: c++, c, qt, qml, custom-component

So, I'm creating an app in QML, and have created a custom component. To be better organized, I  am placing all of my custom components in a "com" subdirectory. I did some research, and found that I needed QML_IMPORT_PATH and a custom qmldir file to create a module so I could import my controls into my project.

My components path is E:/Qt Projects/MyApp/qml/MyApp/com

Inside, I created a qmldir.txt file containing the following:

```
Button 1.0 Button.qml
```

Where "Button.qml" is the name of my custom component (in the same directory).

```
//Button.qml
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 50
}
```

Next I went to "MyApp.Pro" and appended the following:

```
QML_IMPORT_PATH = E:/Qt Projects
```

Finally, I went to MyApp.qml and added:

```
import MyApp.qml.MyApp.com 1.0
```

Yet, I am still getting a "module not found" error on that line. When it shows the error during mouseover, it displays a list of the current import paths, and E:/Qt Projects wasn't one of them. I've cleaned, rebuilt my project, ran qmake and everything. Still not working. Is my syntax wrong? Why won't it find my module? I'm a Qt newbie so forgive me if this is a stupid question. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having spaces in paths is strongly discouraged...

Comment: Could that be the cause?

Comment: @Nickersoft: have you tried with QtProjects for a quick test?

Comment: qmldir should not has extension. only qmldir. And also in
QML_IMPORT_PATH = E:/Qt Projects pls add E:/Qt Projects with ". like:
QML_IMPORT_PATH = "E:/Qt Projects"